# What do I need to do to ensure the longevity of my Welsh dresser?

Tags: wooden-furniture

Around 2008 my Mum gifted us her Welsh dresser which I believe is pine, or possibly a slightly harder wood with a similar colour/tone. We occasionally (who am I kidding; maybe twice a year) polish it with Mr Sheen/Pledge, but nothing more. And even that is only on the top of the sideboard and maybe the doors. Do I need to be performing any sort of ir/regular maintenance to ensure the longevity of the piece? Should I apply some form of wax annually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Keep it in a house (*i.e.* a dry, somewhat climate controlled environment) and it will become an antique, or more antique, in the old fashioned way, by existing.

Waxing/polishing are purely cosmetic, and should be done before your Mum visits to keep her happy.

The basic construction of wooden furniture dictates its odds of becoming antique / more antique. Once it's gotten to antique status, short of wood eating pests it's generally good to become more antique until some external event ends it. So make sure your smoke detectors are working, etc...

Comment: Thanks, that's useful input. It's in the dining room away from direct sunlight, not near a radiator and the humidity here in the UK is pretty stable indoors. I shall leave it to mature.